# Python Regular Expression. Matching once or twice pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a bunch of lines in a file with either one or two occurences of same pattern (id=):

```
Linetype1 : ...id=1234...id=4321...value=5678... # "..." means whatever
Linetype2 : ...id=7890...value=8765
```

I thought I could write such a regex to grep all my ids and associated values:

```
>>> l="...id=1234...id=4321...value=5678...\n...id=7890...value=8765\n"
>>> ret = re.findall('(id=[0-9]+).*?(id=[0-9]+)*.*?(value=[0-9]+)',l)
[('id=1234', '', 'value=5678'), ('id=7890', '', 'value=8765')]
```

I can't get the second "id=4321" part.
This looks very strange to me since I use the non-greedy .*? between first id=[0-9]+ and second.

Answer (score 0):

The middle of your regex has

```
(id=[0-9]+)*
```

The empty string matches this, since it is under the Kleene star `*`. So the regex engine proceeds through the string as follows:

- find the first `id=[0-9]+` group
- expand `.*?` to the empty string, since it matches
- expand `(id=[0-9]+)`* to the empty string, since it matches
- expand `.*?` to the rest of the string

If you replace the middle group's quantifier with `+`, or just remove it entirely, then it works.

Comment: Yes, but then it does not match the linetype2 anymore